# iPhone 2.5D code samples

Tags: iphone, objective-c, 2.5d

I'm looking for code samples that use 2.5D graphic for iPhone development. Anyone has some resources to share with?

Comment: What programming language do you want to use, or doesn't that matter? And is OpenGL okay?

Comment: objective c would be great. And yes, OpenGL is ok;)

Answer (score 3):

For code samples, you might like to check out the [cocos2d book](http://www.apress.com/9781430233039) from Apress. Chapter 11 deals with [creating isometric '2.5d' games using tilemaps,](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2010/09/cocos2d-book-chapter-12-physics-engines-box2d-chipmunk/) which sounds like what you're looking for.

The Objective-C source code is available from the [product page,](http://www.apress.com/9781430233039) but the book itself is well worth purchasing and reading.

Comment: +1, thanks for chapter 11. I've already learned cocos2d, but only to create 2d games